# Identify proper label for a concept

Tags: single-word-requests

I am a psychometrician working on a new project to measure people's beliefs about technology. Our way of measuring people's beliefs is through a set of questions that are supposed to collectively reflect the intended concept.

My problem is as follows: while I have been able to develop a set of statements, I struggle to find the name (or label) that best matches the concepts I want to measure. The concepts are measured using the following statements:

Concept A:

1. A large part of what can be done with <this system> is beyond my grasp.
2. I only know a small subset of what I could do with <this system>.
3. Many of the functionalities offered by <this system> are unknown to me.
4. I do not know most of what can be done with <this system>.

Concept B:

1. The great diversity of uses offered by <this system> confuses me.
2. I cannot get my head around the very different things that can be done with <this system>.
3. I am confused by the very different ways in which <this system> can be used.
4. I struggle to wrap my mind around the disparate functionalities of <this system>.

Concept C:

1. I tend to be confused when I hear about the new ways of using <this system>.
2. I have difficulties getting a grasp of the new ways of using <this system>.
3. I tend to be confused when new ways of using <this system> arise.
4. My understanding of <this system> is disturbed by the new ways of using it.

What would be, in your opinion, the name of the concepts best reflected by these statements? The term "the system" may be replaced by any general consumer technology (social media, communication devices, etc.). I thank you very much in advance for your help in this research project!

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Please **restrict your question to one thing.** You can't accept different parts of different answers. Please see the [help for word-requests](/tags/single-word-requests/info): you need to define your concept(s) in order that the community can suggest words for them. If you don't have some idea of what you're asking about, how did you come up with four sentences?

Comment: Aha. You attempted to define a new HTML tag, "<this system>". I've corrected that.

Comment: The questions seem to be more about people's understanding (in various ways such a scope, scale, complexity) than their beliefs. It seems strange that you are trying to measure something, but you don't know what you are trying to measure.

Comment: I read capabilities, diversity, and confusion, but I find the 12 questions to be the same question.

Comment: @WeatherVane you are absolutely right, these things are typically done the other way around. However, we have a working definition for each of the concepts, we are simply struggling to identify the label that best reflects those definitions.

Comment: Any labels will terribly distort the data collection process. Try the same questionnaire with different labels if you don't believe me. This is how all those political campaign statistics come about - they label things so as to invoke bias.

Answer (score 1):

For Concept A #2-#4 can be framed as a *lack of knowledge* of the system, meaning that these situations can be overcome by reading the docs to learn about the functionality of the system. Reading the docs can overcome this. **Note** that Concept A #1 seems to belong to Concept B.

Concept B seems to be a *lack of imagination*. On could, for instance, understand how blockchain and cryptocurrencies work, but still not be able to come up with real-world uses that are non-trivial. Many people get the sense that blockchain would be useful or that crypto will take over the world, but they can't really understand the ramifications or why such a technology is useful. Brainstorming or studying existing use cases can overcome this.

Concept C seems to be a lack of the fundamental concepts underlying the tech's interface, and can be framed as a *lack of intuition* surrounding use of the tech. A bit esoteric, but in programming languages, handling asynchronous statements or old styles of multithreading often cause this pain. One cannot simply frame their reasoning about the system based on old system. A new way of thinking is required, but it's not obvious even when a new way or reasoning is spelled out. Experience and practice can overcome this.

Answer (score 0):

The first question, at least, is answered by using the word **potentiality**/**potentialities**.

> *potentiality* [noun] [mass noun]
>
> 1. Latent qualities or abilities that may be developed and lead to future success or usefulness.
>
> - *the technology is still relatively not well known, in spite of its great potentiality*

[[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/potentiality)]

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/potentiality) licenses the plural usage:

> *potentiality* [noun]
>
> [plural *potentialities*] ...

As does [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/potentialities):

> ...
>
> - *But these are achievements of modern rational mechanics, coupled with the potentialities of anti-ice [He leaned down close to me.
>   Baxter, Stephen ANTI-ICE (2003)]*

You could use

- *I'm not fully au fait with the potentialities of this system.*

Answer (score 0):

Most of the items center around familiarity with *what you can do with the system, its uses*, and *ways of using it*—in other words, its **applications.**

**application** (n.)

> *Capacity for practical use* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/applications)

> Practical use or relevance.
>
> *The chip has obvious application to measuring toxins relevant to bioterrorism, he said.* [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/application)

---

> Such an information system has many potential **applications**. Some of
> those projected for this demonstration include: ... [NASA; *First
> Comprehensive Symposium on the Practical **Application** of Earth
> Resources Survey Data*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/First_Comprehensive_Symposium_on_the_Pra/If60UTY4ot4C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=the%20system%20has%20many%20practical%20applications&pg=PA1506&printsec=frontcover) (1975)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to me to be a concept that unifies all three of your fuzzy and label-less concepts, and that is the **knowledge gap** that exists in the subjects you are studying.

That knowledge gap is evident in the subjects' inability to

- use the system in even the most basic way
- apply the system in inventive and diverse ways
- understand the potential of the system to evolve heuristically, expansively

These three gaps seem cumulative by nature, with each gap requiring an increasing amount of expertise to bridge.

For example, I can grasp how to use a mouse in the most basic of ways, such as clicking on a box or icon, but to use a mouse to cut and paste requires more knowledge. When I acquire more knowledge and my ease of use increases, then I might be able to use a mouse to draw a picture on my monitor and then print a hard copy. In other words, a progression of knowledge unfolds before me, and my expertise expands.

Then comes the almost intuitive ability to understand the potential that exists in the system to branch out with new applications. In other words, the heuristic possibilities become clearer. Call them "new horizons" or "variations," if you like, but the common factor seems to be novelty.

Once I discover I can use a mouse to draw, I am empowered potentially to expand that drawing ability to design a pie chart, complete with colors, labels, and text (both inside and outside the slices of pie). To me, the new possibilities may excite me and motivate me to find shortcuts and discover new applications for the system. For example, I may be able to abstract the system's drawing capabilities and then use them to produce a piece of fine art.

In short, a knowledge gap can serve to motivate subjects to expand their repertoires in using the system, to the point where they may be able to teach novices and newbies the tricks of the trade.

Comment: Thank you very much, your comment regarding the knowledge gap is right on point. I had never thought of your suggestion to view these three concepts as steps that follow one another, I'll give this some thought. I may use the example that you provide as discussion points, thank for your input.

Comment: @Jean-CharlesPillet: You are welcome! You posed a good question. Don